# Linking to libGL adds references to NVidia libraries

Tags: c, linux, opengl, nvidia, dynamic-linking

I am trying to link my program to the libGL.so library, but my executable also ends up with references to libnvidia-tls.so.331.62 and libnvidia-glcore.so.331.62. Even though the NVidia driver will be required to execute my program (I use CUDA), I do not want it to depend on a specific version of the library (driver).

Here is a minimal example; source:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glEnd();

    return 0;
}
```

I build the program with:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lGL
```

Output of `ldd main`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6c3fc000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd4f37c5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd4f33fd000)
libnvidia-tls.so.331.62 => /usr/lib/nvidia-331/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.331.62 (0x00007fd4f31f9000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.331.62 => /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.62 (0x00007fd4f09ea000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fd4f06b5000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fd4f04a2000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd4f029e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd4f3b21000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd4eff9a000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fd4efd7b000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fd4efb77000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fd4ef971000)
```

(notice the references to libnvidia-tls and libnvidia-glcore).

I get the same results if I compile with `g++ -o main main.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`.

Output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4d5d8000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fa63dfd5000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa63ddc3000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fa63dbbf000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fa63d9b9000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fa63d7b7000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa63d481000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fa63d26a000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fa63d065000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa63ce46000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fa63cc40000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fa63ca34000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa63c816000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa63c612000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa63c24a000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa63c045000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa63be3f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa63e482000)
```

Note that there is nothing about nvidia libs here.

Edit: output of `readelf -d main | grep NEEDED`:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libGL.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: What's the output of `readelf -d t main | grep NEEDED` ? (

Comment: I added it to the question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ldd` command doesn't do what you think it does.

The `ldd` command shows you all the library dependencies, both direct and indirect, that a program or library has.  So it will show `libGL.so.1`, which you use directly, and `libnvidia-tls.so.331.62`, which you use indirectly.

The `readelf -d` command will show you only the libraries your program uses directly: `libGL.so.1` and `libc.so.6`.

In other words, the reference to `libnvidia-tls.so.331.62` is not in your program.  It is in a library that your program uses.  If you move your program to another system, you may see another library in its place.

Comment: Which means that my program is most likely already compatible with a system using a different version of the nvidia driver, and I actually did not have any problem in the first place ? Thanks ! (Note: I think you mean readelf -d -t, using readelf -d t gives me "t: no such file")

Comment: "readelf -d t main" gives me "readelf: Error: 't': No such file", then "File: main" followed by the same result as readelf -d main

Comment: @personne3000: You're right, that `t` doesn't belong there.